# sequelize model versioning and optimistic

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am wondering if there was an easy way to add versioning to model for easy optimistic concurrency. I was curious if anyone here has integrated that into their project with sequelize and got it to work seamless, without having to manually add the version to the where of every update ect.
I started with something like this

```
export const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true},
  name: {type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false}
}, {
  underscored: true,
  tableName: 'r_users',
  version: true // <- here
});
```

but the version doesn't change when updating the record or migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration version can be found in SequelizeMeta but to select from it you need to add quotes 'SequelizeMeta' or change the name of the table to sequelize_meta by add

```
"migrationStorageTableName": "sequelize_meta",
```

to the config